# Is there a situation where and and or means the same thing?

Tags: grammar, semantics

> I am sure you didn't read the documentation and understand the
> document.
>
> I am sure you didn't read the documentation or understand the
> document.

The first one means you didn't do either.

The second one means you did either one of them or none.

But the second one can also mean you didn't do either.

Is this correct or I am crazy dumb?

Comment: *I am sure you are not crazy and dumb.*  How's that compared to *I am sure you are not crazy or dumb*.

Comment: Logical inferences cannot be drawn from sentences as elliptical as yours.  It's a  waste of time.   You can only understand a text if you have read it. You can only misunderstand a text if you have read it.  If you didn't read it, you cannot understand or misunderstand it.  You might be capable of understanding it, should you read it.  You might be likely to misunderstand it, should you read it.

Comment: You're trying to insert a knife between two slices of American burger cheese, from which the slice separator was omitted. No-one will ever truly know which cheese molecules belonged to which slice originally.

Comment: You can read a dozen questions about the ambiguities of "or" in English. It's not uncommon for "or" and "and" to both be possible. You can ask someone "Would you like something to eat or drink?" and mean the same as "Would you like something to eat and drink?" - they can have both in each case. In your specific case it's impossible to understand the document without having read it, so logically it's a bit different, and it depends on what you want to emphasise or what you think happened - you might think they maybe read it but be certain they didn't understand.

Comment: @StuartF - that reminds me of a practical lesson from a Japanese friend, that when addressing a Japanese native, even in English, you should avoid questions such as "Would you like tea or coffee?" because the answer is invariably "Yes." You then have to separately ask which…